# Difficulty calculating slope for a set of rotated and shifted ellipses, sometimes inverted, sometimes completely wrong

Tags: python, opencv, math, trigonometry, curve-fitting

I am using OpenCV-Python to fit an ellipse to the shape of a droplet.
Then I choose a line, which represents the surface the droplet is resting on.
I calculate the tangents at the intersection of the surface and the ellipse to get the contact angle of the droplet.
It works most of the time, but in some cases, the tangents are flipped upside down or just wrong.
It seems that the calculation for the slope of the tangent fails.
Can someone tell me why this happens?

Here you can see how it should look like (surface at y=250):
[image: Ok Result]

And this is the result when I choose a surface level of y=47:
[image: Flipped]

I did some research and I need to detect which of the two `maj_ax, min_ax` was parallel to the x-Axis before the ellipse gets rotated by `phi` or else the slope calculation algorithm fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```py
from math import cos, sin, pi, sqrt, tan, atan2, radians
import cv2

class Droplet():
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_valid = False
        self.angle_l = 0
        self.angle_r = 0
        self.center = (0,0)
        self.maj = 0
        self.min = 0
        self.phi = 0.0
        self.tilt_deg = 0
        self.foc_pt1 = (0,0)
        self.foc_pt2 = (0,0)
        self.tan_l_m = 0
        self.int_l = (0,0)
        self.line_l = (0,0,0,0)
        self.tan_r_m = 0
        self.int_r = (0,0)
        self.line_r = (0,0,0,0)
        self.base_diam = 0
        
def evaluate_droplet(img, y_base) -> Droplet:
    drplt = Droplet()
    crop_img = img[:y_base,:]
    shape = img.shape
    height = shape[0]
    width = shape[1]
    # values only for 8bit images!
    bw_edges = cv2.Canny(crop_img, 76, 179)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bw_edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    if len(contours) == 0:
        raise ValueError('No contours found!')

    edge = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    (x0,y0),(maj_ax,min_ax),phi_deg = cv2.fitEllipse(edge)

    phi = radians(phi_deg) # to radians
    a = maj_ax/2
    b = min_ax/2

    intersection = calc_intersection_line_ellipse((x0,y0,a,b,phi),(0,y_base))
    if intersection is None:
        raise ValueError('No intersections found')
    # select left and right intersection points
    x_int_l = min(intersection)
    x_int_r = max(intersection)

    foc_len = sqrt(abs(a**2 - b**2))

    # calc slope and angle of tangent
    m_t_l = calc_slope_of_ellipse((x0,y0,a,b,phi), x_int_l, y_base)
    angle_l = pi - atan2(m_t_l,1)
 
    m_t_r = calc_slope_of_ellipse((x0,y0,a,b,phi), x_int_r, y_base)
    angle_r = atan2(m_t_r,1) + pi

    drplt.angle_l = angle_l
    drplt.angle_r = angle_r
    drplt.maj = maj_ax
    drplt.min = min_ax
    drplt.center = (x0, y0)
    drplt.phi = phi
    drplt.tilt_deg = phi_deg
    drplt.tan_l_m = m_t_l
    drplt.tan_r_m = m_t_r
    drplt.line_l = (int(round(x_int_l - (int(round(y_base))/m_t_l))), 0, int(round(x_int_l + ((height - int(round(y_base)))/m_t_l))), int(round(height)))
    drplt.line_r = (int(round(x_int_r - (int(round(y_base))/m_t_r))), 0, int(round(x_int_r + ((height - int(round(y_base)))/m_t_r))), int(round(height)))
    drplt.int_l = (x_int_l, y_base)
    drplt.int_r = (x_int_r, y_base)
    drplt.foc_pt1 = (x0 + foc_len*cos(phi), y0 + foc_len*sin(phi))
    drplt.foc_pt2 = (x0 - foc_len*cos(phi), y0 - foc_len*sin(phi))
    drplt.base_diam = x_int_r - x_int_l
    drplt.is_valid = True
    
    # draw ellipse and lines
    img = cv2.drawContours(img,contours,-1,(100,100,255),2)
    img = cv2.drawContours(img,edge,-1,(255,0,0),2)
    img = cv2.ellipse(img, (int(round(x0)),int(round(y0))), (int(round(a)),int(round(b))), int(round(phi*180/pi)), 0, 360, (255,0,255), thickness=1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    y_int = int(round(y_base))
    img = cv2.line(img, (int(round(x_int_l - (y_int/m_t_l))), 0), (int(round(x_int_l + ((height - y_int)/m_t_l))), int(round(height))), (255,0,255), thickness=1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    img = cv2.line(img, (int(round(x_int_r - (y_int/m_t_r))), 0), (int(round(x_int_r + ((height - y_int)/m_t_r))), int(round(height))), (255,0,255), thickness=1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    img = cv2.ellipse(img, (int(round(x_int_l)),y_int), (20,20), 0, 0, -int(round(angle_l*180/pi)), (255,0,255), thickness=1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    img = cv2.ellipse(img, (int(round(x_int_r)),y_int), (20,20), 0, 180, 180 + int(round(angle_r*180/pi)), (255,0,255), thickness=1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    img = cv2.line(img, (0,y_int), (width, y_int), (255,0,0), thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    img = cv2.putText(img, '<' + str(round(angle_l*180/pi,1)), (5,y_int-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, .5, (0,0,0))
    img = cv2.putText(img, '<' + str(round(angle_r*180/pi,1)), (width - 80,y_int-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, .5, (0,0,0))
    cv2.imshow('Test',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return drplt

def calc_intersection_line_ellipse(ellipse_pars, line_pars):
    """
    calculates intersection(s) of an ellipse with a line  
    :param ellipse_pars: tuple of (x0,y0,a,b,phi): x0,y0 center of ellipse; a,b sem-axis of ellipse; phi tilt rel to x axis  
    :param line_pars: tuple of (m,t): m is the slope and t is intercept of the intersecting line  
    :returns: x-coordinate(s) of intesection as list or float or none if none found
    """
    ## -->> http://quickcalcbasic.com/ellipse%20line%20intersection.pdf
    (x0, y0, h, v, phi) = ellipse_pars
    (m, t) = line_pars
    y = t - y0
    try:
        a = v**2 * cos(phi)**2 + h**2 * sin(phi)**2
        b = 2*y*cos(phi)*sin(phi) * (v**2 - h**2)
        c = y**2 * (v**2 * sin(phi)**2 + h**2 * cos(phi)**2) - (h**2 * v**2)
        det = b**2 - 4*a*c
        if det > 0:
            x1 = int(round((-b - sqrt(det))/(2*a) + x0))
            x2 = int(round((-b + sqrt(det))/(2*a) + x0))
            return x1,x2
        elif det == 0:
            x = int(round(-b / (2*a)))
            return x
        else:
            return None
    except Exception as ex:
        raise ex
 
def calc_slope_of_ellipse(ellipse_pars, x, y):
    """
    calculates the slope of the tangent at point x,y, the point needs to be on the ellipse!
    :param ellipse_params: tuple of (x0,y0,a,b,phi): x0,y0 center of ellipse; a,b sem-axis of ellipse; phi tilt rel to x axis  
    :param x: x-coord where the slope will be calculated  
    :returns: the slope of the tangent 
    """
    (x0, y0, a, b, phi) = ellipse_pars
    # transform to non-rotated ellipse
    x_rot = (x - x0)*cos(phi) + (y - y0)*sin(phi)
    y_rot = (x - x0)*sin(phi) + (y - y0)*cos(phi)
    m_rot = -(b**2 * x_rot)/(a**2 * y_rot) # slope of tangent to unrotated ellipse
    #rotate tangent line back to angle of the rotated ellipse
    m_tan = tan(atan2(m_rot,1) + phi)

    return m_tan

if __name__ == "__main__":
    im = cv2.imread('untitled1.png')
    # any value below 250 is just the droplet without the substrate
    drp = evaluate_droplet(im, 250)
```

Original image:
[image: Original image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I made a mistake in `calc_slope_ellipse`:
   `x_rot = (x - x0)*cos(phi) + (y - y0)*sin(phi)`
   should be
   `x_rot = (x - x0)*cos(phi) - (y - y0)*sin(phi)`
   this fixes the wrong sign of the slope at y=47.
2. I replaced the atan2:

```py
m_rot = -(b**2 * x_rot)/(a**2 * y_rot) # slope of tangent to unrotated ellipse
#rotate tangent line back to angle of the rotated ellipse
m_tan = tan(atan2(m_rot,1) + phi)
```

with

```py
tan_a = x_rot/a**2
tan_b = y_rot/b**2
#rotate tangent line back to angle of the rotated ellipse
tan_a_r = tan_a*cos(phi) + tan_b*sin(phi)
tan_b_r = tan_b*cos(phi) - tan_a*sin(phi)
m_tan = - (tan_a_r / tan_b_r)
```

This fixes the weird behaviour for certain cases (y=62).

Complete fcn:

```py
def calc_slope_of_ellipse(ellipse_pars, x, y):
    (x0, y0, a, b, phi) = ellipse_pars

    # transform to non-rotated ellipse centered to origin
    x_rot = (x - x0)*cos(phi) - (y - y0)*sin(phi)
    y_rot = (x - x0)*sin(phi) + (y - y0)*cos(phi)
    # Ax + By = C
    tan_a = x_rot/a**2
    tan_b = y_rot/b**2
    #rotate tangent line back to angle of the rotated ellipse
    tan_a_r = tan_a*cos(phi) + tan_b*sin(phi)
    tan_b_r = tan_b*cos(phi) - tan_a*sin(phi)
    m_tan = - (tan_a_r / tan_b_r)

    return m_tan
```